# Do DeMorgan's laws hold for pseudo-complement in Bi-Heyting Algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

A textbook says in Heyting Algebra,

> The pseudo-complement of an element $a$ is denoted as $a^{\ast}$.
>   One of the DeMorgan's law $\left(\vee a_{i}\right)^{\ast}=\wedge a_{i}^{\ast}$ holds whenever $\vee a_{i}$ makes sense. Note that the other DeMorgan's law, i.e. $\left(\wedge a_{i}\right)^{\ast}=\vee a_{i}^{\ast}$ does not hold in general.

Firstly, is this correct?

If I consider the duality, in co-Heyting Algebra,

> The pseudo-complement of an element $a$ is denoted as $a^{\ast}$.
>   One of the DeMorgan's law $\left(\vee a_{i}\right)^{\ast}=\wedge a_{i}^{\ast}$ does not hold in general. But the other DeMorgan's law, i.e. $\left(\wedge a_{i}\right)^{\ast}=\vee a_{i}^{\ast}$ holds.

Secondary, is this correct?

Finally, if we consider bi-Heyting Algebra, Do both of the DeMorgan's laws hold?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is correct. A quick way to convice you intuitively of that is by considering constructive logic:

$\neg(x\wedge \neg x)$ is provable in constructive logic (that's the Law of non-contradiction). If $\neg(x\wedge y) \equiv \neg x \vee \neg y$ where true in general then $\neg x \vee \neg \neg x$ would too. But this is a weakened form of the Law of excluded middle and in general not true.

Your second statement is a bit confusing: In a co-Heyting algebra we have a co-pseudo-complement, not generally a pseudo-complement. Obviously now the dual DeMorgan law holds for the co-pseudo-complement, but not the original. So in a bi-Heyting algebra it is still not generally true that the pseudo-complement satisfies both DeMorgan laws.